# Jquery Mobile - Address Bar Pops down

Tags: jquery, mobile, iphone

I'm using jQuery Mobile to build a Mobile Web App... The problem I'm having happens when calling "internal" urls using the # syntax. For example, I have the following code:

About

Whenever someone "taps" on this link on the iPhone, the address bar (which is hidden at time of tapping) pops down and displays the new link and then pops back up into the "hidden" position. I should also say that the browser is not going to another page, it's just hiding the current page and then showing a div with id="about" (hidden at time of tap).

Anyway, I would like to make mobile safari not do this whenever someone taps on a link in my mobile app. Does anyone know a way to get rid of this using javascript, meta tags or any other method?

Thanks.

Comment: It must be possible because the following web app navigates without any address bar popping down (iPhone, Safari):
http://www.tagesanzeiger.ch/mobileapp/

Answer (score 0):

This may help answer your question: [Current state of Jquery history/back-button plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513106/current-state-of-jquery-history-back-button-plugins)

Basically, you need to handle the history yourself, and not rely on the browser to change URL for you. This can be accomplished in HTML5 very easily using the history stack of the browser.

Also, it would help to show your code. That way we can see what you're trying to do and offer suggestions directly applicable to your code.