# Current state of Jquery history/back-button plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, browser-history

I spent a long time looking into this about a year ago,
I tried:

- [Jquery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)
- [Jquery History plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/)
- [jquery .address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

I found the jquery.address plugin to be the best, but these things change quickly.

Has anyone thoroughly researched the options for this RECENTLY? Keen to hear some thoughts before I integrate jquery.address again (I didn't have any issues with it before)

Comment: "best"? In what way? What functionality/features are you after?

Comment: None of them make use of the new HTML5 History interface supported in the recent Chromes and Firefox 4.

Comment: @Andy - i think jquery bbq does?

Comment: @Richard - not totally sure. I remember getting frustrated with jqyery.history. Just keen to get someone's experience of a plugin they thought was brilliant.

Comment: @Haroldo: BBQ only uses the hash/hashchange features of HTML 5.  It doesn't appear to make use of `pushState` or `replaceState`.

Comment: I know that Sammy.js(http://sammyjs.org/) in github has good support for pushState functionality - but I'm not sure if that is based upon one of these plugins.  I also know that jQuery BBQ was written by the guy who recently re-did params in jQuery 1.4.x, so that would lend me a sense of confidence in jQuery BBQ.

Answer (score 8):

I am the author of [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) which as SnippetSpace has said in his answer works with the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) with an optional hash-fallback for older browsers. The HTML5 History API allows you to modify the url directly, so no need for hashes anymore! Yay!

For a listing of the current situation of back/forward plugins you can check here:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

As the HTML5 History API is a [proper solution](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling) to the back/forward/hash/hashbang problem, it's really the way to go compared to the old hashchange solutions. Problems with hashes include: double load when accessing a hashed url, different urls, sharing hashed links with js-disabled users don't work.

There is one other plugin which supports the HTML5 History API which is [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/), however it does not support things like replaceState and I'm unsure of it's actual cross-browser support for the HTML5 History API. But looking at it's [list of issues](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address/issues) I'm saying that it's support isn't that well.

Comment: Since the older IEs wont be supporting history.pushState, if we're linking to specific states externally, we'd have to implement redirects on the origin site to redirect to the hash states, no?

Comment: @meder History.js handles that for you. For instance `History.pushState(null,null,'?somestate')` in IE will change the url to `http://mysite.com/#?somestate`, whereas for HTML5 browsers it will change it to `http://mysite.com/?somestate`. For the hash-fallback for IE/HTML4-Browsers, it is completely transparent, and requires no extra handling in your code.

Comment: I understand that aspect of it, but I'm referring to linking to a **specific state from an external website**. I suppose the right way is to never link to the hash state but link to the regular state, eg `/?somestate` and program the application to do the state changing.. yeah?

Comment: pretty much like your history.js - will give it a try

Comment: @mender correct, links should be to the non-hashed url. Although using the hashed url will also work. If a HTML5 browser accesses a hashed url, it will convert it to the HTML5 state.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked trough this and have researched them and indeed those 3 are the best. I like history.js because it supports html5 history management that changes the URL instead of adding hashes :). At least that's what the author told me.